# How was the lost F35 from the Queen Elizabeth recovered?

Tags: accident-investigation, f-35

In 2021, an F35 Lightning II from the Royal Navy carrier Queen Elizabeth crashed into the sea on take-off.
It was [later reported](https://news.sky.com/story/f-35-fighter-jet-wreckage-of-aircraft-that-plunged-into-the-mediterranean-recovered-and-sailor-arrested-for-allegedly-leaking-footage-12489624) that the aircraft was recovered from a mile below the Mediterranean.
Has there been any further public information about *how* the aircraft was recovered,  what equipment was used, and whether the whole aircraft was raised or just the sensitive equipment that they carry?

Comment: The recovery was likely done the same way the other F-35 in the South China sea was recovered. There are pictures of the recovered aircraft here: https://theaviationist.com/2022/01/21/photo-recovered-f-35b-wreckage/